# How to get a tag value inside an attribute?

Tags: jquery

```
<li id="test">
   <a title="<span class='something1'>Some text</span> <br />
   <span class='something2'>Some text 2</span>"></a>
</li>
```

Is it possible to get "Some text 2"?

alert(what?)

UPD: The code works with [jQuery Tooltip Plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html), but is it possible to get a value?

UPD2: Thanks, GolezTrol. I don't know why, but it didn't cross my mind that I should check the plugin. If anyone needs it later:

```
var title_text = $('#test > a').attr('title');

alert($(this).tooltip().getTip().find(".something2").text());
```

Comment: This isn't even valid HTML. If you need to put `<` and `>` in an attribute, you should escape it.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: It works with jQuery Tooltip http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Comment: Technically it is valid since it's enclosed within quotations, and non of the elements use double quotes. Try `$('#wrapper a').attr('title');`

Comment: See your UPD now. If it works with the plugin, you can just peek into the source of that, right? :) You can use FireBug to step through to code and easily find the line that retrieves the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get attribute text, create jquery object with it and search inside that object

```
var title = $('a.my_link').attr('title');
$(title).find('.something2');
```

Although, it makes a little sense to put html markup in title attribute, as browser will display it as plain text.

**edit**
Create a common root for your title contents, e.g. put it all in `<span>...</span>`:
http://jsfiddle.net/pZqJj/

Or, if you're absolutely sure search target will stay on top level, use `filter` instead of `find`.

Comment: It says "[object Object]" and with ".text()" it returns an empty string. Browser shows all those spans with jQuery Tools Tooltip.

Comment: @Daniel Please check an example

Comment: You are right, your code works. I removed the plugin and it worked. It doesn't work with the plugin though. I guess I'll have to dig the source as GolezTrol suggested.

Comment: Maybe the plugin clears the title to prevent the html to show up in a regular hint window?

Answer (score 2):

You can.

You can get the attribute value:

```
var value = $('#wrapper a').attr('title');
```

Then, you can jQuery that string:

```
alert($(value).find('.something2').text());
```

Comment: That is valid html, as **Brad** notes.

Comment: That's maybe because you renamed your `li` to `test` while it was named `wrapper` when I wrote my example. :)